# How to Optimize Reactive implementation of recursive function

Tags: c#, recursion, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I tried creating a custom Reactive timer with dynamic intervals in C# using Rx library. Since I needed most optimized code in both performance and no. of lines I ended up using recursive approach. Code is below:

```
  public static IObservable<TOut> GenerateAsync<TResult, TOut>(
  Func<Task<TResult>> initialState,
  Func<TResult, bool> condition,
  Func<TResult, Task<TResult>> iterate,
  Func<TResult, TimeSpan> timeSelector,
  Func<TResult, TOut> resultSelector,
  IScheduler scheduler = null)
    {
        var s = scheduler ?? Scheduler.Default;

        return Observable.Create<TOut>(async obs =>
        {
            //You have to do your initial time delay here.
            var init = await initialState();

            //Process the result
            obs.OnNext(resultSelector(init));

            return s.Schedule(init, timeSelector(init), async (state, recurse) =>
            {
                //Check if we are done
                if (!condition(state))
                {
                    obs.OnCompleted();
                    return;
                }

                //Initiate the next request
                state = await iterate(state);

                //Process the result
                obs.OnNext(resultSelector(state));

                //Recursively schedule again
                recurse(state, timeSelector(state));

            });
        });
    }
```

The problem with this approach is that since it is recursive hence there is a tremendous stack growth. I tested this approach against the timer usage and it memory usage is almost double.

[Link](https://goo.gl/sAi4w6) for testing code with i used to get memory usage test.

How can i optimize this function without losing its usage capability?

Comment: Note that the default stack size per thread is 4MB on 64 bit. So don't have a stack growth but a heap growth hear. You probably have some code leaking. Check with a memory profiler.

Comment: I have looked into the heap growth basically the sate variable that we are passing recursively is causing heap memory to grow... How can i resolve this?

Comment: As you know heap is managed by the garbage collector. If your state is accumulating in the heap, you should ask why it is not being garbage collector. Is your state instances being referenced by something ? You can check that via WinDBG + SOS or perfview or some other profiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a bit of a mishmash of Tasks and Observables - Observables alone are sufficiently expressive.

To answer your basic question - it is to create an interval timer with a mutable time period, one which is supplied while the timer runs. This can be expressed as an observable which takes an observable of `TimeSpan` as input and returns ticks as output, much like the built-in `Observable.Interval`.

```
    static IObservable<long> MutableInterval(IObservable<TimeSpan> period, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return period.Select(timespan => Observable.Interval(timespan, scheduler))
                     .Switch()
                     .Scan(0L, (a, _) => a + 1);
    }
```

Here's a test with a slowly decreasing period:

```
 var slowlyDecreasing =
                Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                          .StartWith(0)
                          .Select(p => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000 / (p + 1)))
                          .Do(p => Console.WriteLine("Period changed to {0}", p)); 

MutableInterval(slowlyDecreasing, Scheduler.Default).Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```